# JSON template in Sitecore 10.1

Tags: sxa, templates, scriban, renderfield, json

Is there any alternate to JSON template in Sitecore 10.1?. We migrated to Sitecore 10.1 from Sitecore 8.

One of the Rendering Variants is JSONResults, which includes JSON Template inside JSONResults. But I don't see that JSON template is working and I couldn't find the JSON template code implementation in any of the Dlls. Is there any alternate to JSON template.

We tried to use Sriban template instead of JSON template but that didn't work.

We have 3 JSON templates in Sitecore 8 which we need to convert in Sitecore 10.1

```
Images: The template value was $linkTool.GetImages($item,"Image Medium").
NavigationLink: The template value was $linkTool.GetLinkUrl($item).
State: The template value was $linkTool.GetItemParent($item).
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON template not working in Sitecore 10.1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35242/json-template-not-working-in-sitecore-10-1)

Comment: Sorry @MichaelWest , I forgot to delete that question